# SQL get values with MAX date by grouping

Tags: sql, group-by

I have database with columns:

**station**, **source**, **type**, **date** and **price**

I would like to get newest price for each type.

I tried

```
SELECT max(date) and GROUP BY station, source, type
```

but error appears "price must appear in GROUP BY clause"

May be someone know how to do it?

Comment: Please tell us which database you're using. Oracle? Mysql? SqlServer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent row for a combination of columns, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by station, source, type order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one-

```
select * from
(    
SELECT station, source, type ,price, row_number() over(partition by type order by date desc) as rn from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: @КириллСмирнов, what is your dbms?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL

Comment: I've updated the query - you can check now it should solve the performance issue @КириллСмирнов